# Why does Tao call it *Continuity of exponentiation*?

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation

I’m self-studying Tao’s *Analysis I*. He states the following.

> **Lemma 6.7.1** (Continuity of exponentiation). *Let $x > 0$, and let $α$ be a real number. Let $(q_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be any sequence of rational numbers converging to $α$. Then $(x^{q_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ is also a convergent sequence. Furthermore, if $(q’_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is any other sequence of rational numbers converging to $α$, then $(x^{q’_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ has the same limit as $(x^{q_n})_{n=1}^\infty$*:
>
> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^{q_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^{q’_n}.$

**Question:** Why does he call this *Continuity of exponentiation*? What is *continuity* in this?

Answer (score 2):

He is just saying that the map $f(q):=x^q$ is continuous.

Comment: He hasn’t defined continuity before.

Comment: Then I would take it just as a word for now, it will become clearer when he will define continuity. Then you'll see the reason for such a word choice.